# Google Analytics reporting API without library

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api

I want to consume the google analytics reporting API in some other server application and in that application, I can only make the HTTP API call to any other third party services and can not include any external library.

Please let me know is there any way to consume the google analytics reporting API without library and consume directly using the HTTP API Call.

I am very new to google analytics and don't know much about google analytics.
any documentation or solutions or suggestions will be very helpful.

Regards,
Nitesh.

Comment: The documentation contains everything you code it yourself https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v4/

Comment: I have checked this document already, but this uses the library and I want to consume Reporting API without using these libraries by directly calling the API Endpoint.

Comment: No if you look at the documentation it tells you what The HTTP POST calls need to look like https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v4/rest/v4/reports/batchGet  The hard part will be the authorization.  Only the examples use the library because using the library is much easier.  I can tell you what you want to do can be done as i have done it.   Your just going to have to look though the documentation.

Comment: Hey Dalm, Thankyou that was very helpful. now, I understood that how to call reporting API. can you please let me how I can overcome that authentication piece?

Comment: or if you have any related code base that you can share that will be very helpful.

Comment: I cant share anything it was for a customer a number of years ago.   If you are only accessing your own analytics account i would say go with a service account but i have never managed to code a service account auth myself manually as it would require to many security libraries which you cant use.   Try this https://www.daimto.com/google-3-legged-oauth2-flow/  Oauth2 will work just store the refresh token and request a new access token when ever you need to access the data.